# JQUERY UI: Load tabs by clicking links in accordion

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-ui-accordion

How can I load ajax content clicking in a link in an accordion and add that content to jquery ui tabs?

I want something like this [PARAM QUERY](http://paramquery.com/demos)

I'm just starting with javascript and jquery so I don't know how to achieve this

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a new tab to the jQuery UI tabs header and then trigger the `refresh` function and `select` that new tab.  Here is a code snippet that should help:

```
var $mytabs = $('#mytabs'), 
    $accordion = $('#accordion'), 
    addTab = function() {
        var time = new Date().getTime();
        $mytabs.find('ui-tabs-nav').filter(':first').append('<li><a href="data.php?t=' + time + '">New Tab!</a></li>').tabs('refresh');
        $mytabs.tabs('refresh').tabs('select', 'data.php?t=' + time
    };
$accordion.accordion({
    activate: addTab
});
```

Comment: At the end I just copied the source code of the page that I mentioned before, erased all except main divs and jquery scripts and its working for me,